# Need to bring back all rows that match a where clause as well as the ones that dont

Tags: mysql

Table

```
ID  Name  int
1   test1 1
2   test2 2
3   test3 0
```

When i run this query

```
SELECT Count(ID) FROM table where int = 1  group by(ID);
```

I get

```
count  Name 
1      test1
```

I need to bing back all the names and only count the ones where int is 1

expected result:

```
count  Name 
1      test1
0      test2
0      test3
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

```
select sum(`int` = 1) as count,
       name
from your_table
group by name
```

#### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/372abf/3)

Answer (score -2):

You may use `IF` to filter out values count having `int` != 1

```
SELECT IF (`int` = 1, SUM(`int`), 0) as count, `name` FROM `table` group by `name`;
```

Comment: @juergend Did you understood the question ? seems not. My query will return count of those records which have `int` value 1 and for other values like 0 & 2 it will return 0.

Comment: Check this out and tell me what you see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/372abf/7

Comment: ohh I see, you meant to say `remove IF()` and put `int = 1` in `sum` function. Then Okay, your comment was incomplete though !

Comment: Now I see that you did not put `int=1` in your `sum()`. My bad. Forget my first comment.